# Многократно повторяются одинаковые заголовки новостей с сайта

Tags: python-3.x, requests, bs4, web-scraping

Я начинающий.О такой штуке как BeautifulSoup узнал пару дней назад.Так что не судите меня строго,если допустил глупую ошибку.Мне захотелось спарсить заголовки главных новостей с championat.com .В итоге получилось,но с одной проблемой(см.Заголовок вопроса).Версия языка 3.9

```
responce=requests.get(championat_url, headers=headers)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(responce.content, 'html.parser')
            items=soup.findAll('div',class_='news-item__content')
            comps=[]

            for item in items:
                    comps.append({ 'title': item.find('a',class_='news-item__title').get_text(strip=True)})
                                                      
                    for comp in comps:
                            print(comps['title'])
```

Как итог:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for item in items:
            comps.append({ 'title': item.find('a',class_='news-item__title').get_text(strip=True)})
                                              
            for comp in comps: # <- тут лишний отступ
                    print(comps['title']) # <- тут неправильное название переменной
```

У вас во-первых лишний отступ, поэтому у вас получился цикл в цикле. А во-вторых вы во втором цикле печатаете не переменную цикла, а весь список каждый раз. Правильно будет, наверное, так:

```
    for item in items:
            comps.append({ 'title': item.find('a',class_='news-item__title').get_text(strip=True)})
                                              
    for comp in comps: 
            print(comp['title'])
```